# 301 Redirect to new directory and without .html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to 301 redirect hundreds of urls in a new directory and without the .html ending.

old URL: `domain.com/content/lorem-ipsum.html`

new URL: `domain.com/new/lorem-ipsum`

so I need a redirect that redirects all URLs from `/content/` to `/new/` **and** a redirect that redirects all urls from `.html` to without `.html`. Or maybe it can be done in one redirect like

old: `domain.com/content/*.html`

new: `domain.com/new/*`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code please.

Comment: Nothing, I have no idea how to do this... I have basic experience in redirects, but this is a level to high. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the [RewriteRule documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and read some tutorials on how to use it:

https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

http://www.elated.com/articles/mod-rewrite-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708

To help you get started and solve your current problem, try this:

```
RewriteEnging On
RewriteRule ^content/(.+)\.html /new/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Demo here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=c73ccb42-e5aa-5e1f-b672-5aac32913912

Explanation: In the *pattern* we are telling the server to look for URLs that start with content - `^content/`, are followed by one or more characters of whatever - `(.+)` and end with .html - `\.html`.

Note the `()` around the `.+` - this instructs Apache to save the match made into a variable - `$1`. So in your example `lorem-ipsum` is stored in `$1`.

`$1` can then be accessed in the *substitution*, where we tell it to go to `/new/`, followed by whatever is stored in `$1`.

Finally in the *flags* section we're instructing Apache to issue a 301 redirect - `R=301` and to stop processing further rules `L`, since we don't need it to for this request which is now being redirected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following redirect :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/dir/(.+)\.html$ http://example.com/new/$1
```